# how can i turn keyboard in iOS6.0?

Tags: iphone, ios6, rotation, uikeyboard

i have a portrait view (status bar hidden), but i turned it. Then keyboard shows this:

[image]

i want keyboard to turn and fullscreen. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dnt need to turn the keyboard , u need to change the orientation of ur view, from potrait to landscape...

Comment: I changed orientation like this: ApplicationDelegate.window.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  ApplicationDelegate.window.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
ApplicationDelegate.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, HEIGHT_iPHONE, WIDTH_iPHONE);

Comment: view changed but status bar did not change. Then I did statusbar hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the comments.
You can't make the screen be landscape like this. IOS 6 has something new, "the app's appDelegate always start as portrait"
You should use the IOS 6 autorotate!
This should be in the appDelegate:

```
  - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application
supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{

    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

In your view controller:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

in the supportedInterfaceOrientations you can set it to landscape only

Comment: in my app delegate like this:                     (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}   and in my view controller                                           (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return [self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

Comment: Do the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation get called in IOS 6 ?

Comment: I've solved. Thanks Sang. I used this example: https://github.com/sunilpandey/DifferentOrientation